# Adding system date to BlueJ class template

Tags: java, bluej

I just got started with BlueJ development, and for my programming projects, I want to be able to document them like so:

```
/*
My Name
The System Date
Program Name
*/
```

As you can see, I want to be able to pull the system date (the date of the creation of the class), so that I can include it in the comments. Is that possible? I know BlueJ uses `$` to notate variables it uses, like `$PKGNAME`, so I was wondering if anyone knew of a variable or property I can use to get the date from the system clock. I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're out of luck:

> The fields you see in the default templates are all there are. There 
>   are no more.
>
> And, yes, you are right: they are not documented any further.
>   You cannot define additional fields yourself.
>   (If there was a good use for it, we could define additional fields. So 
>   if you got a useful idea, tell us.)
>
> Michael

Taken from the discussion [BlueJ file templates: .tmpl file variables](http://lists.bluej.org/pipermail/bluej-discuss/2002-September/001465.html).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in windows. I've done it. I just can't do it in linux. I'll Switch to windows and tell you.
----Update---

Ok, so you need to go to C:\Program Files\BlueJ\lib\english\templates\newclass (Assuming it's installed for all users. Otherwise you'll have to go to the single user location)

There's a readme file on how to create a template file, but the easiest way is to copy the stdclass.tmpl file, then edit that. It's laid out in almost plain javadoc.